# Can't select option: element is found but invisible

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a website which is not under my control, so I can't change its HTML and CSS. I need to select an option from a combo box.

I can successfully find a "select ../>" element but when I try to select an option via SelectByText, ByValue, ByIndex it results in the ElementNotVisibleException. The html is pretty complex on that page and I believe that developers assigned "display:none" by a css-style. I can navigate to the "div" which contains that combo box and click on it via Actions but it doesn't help to select an option after that. After such a click I see for a second the options on the screen and then the combo box collapses.

Is it possible at all to overcome such a problem?

Comment: Not a duplicate of the question linked.  That is a question about scraping, this is a question about interacting with UI elements on the page.  Note that the solution in the linked question does not answer the question being asked here.

Answer (score 3):

Since Selenium API tries to be "user-centric" it will not allow interaction with non-visible elements.  There are two approaches you can try:

1) Click on the `select` element, then perform an explicit wait for the `option` to become visible.  This is useful if the page is using JavaScript to display the select options which can cause slight delay.

```java
By bySelect = By.id("id_of_select_element");
By byOption = new ByChained(bySelect, By.xpath(".//option[contains(text(), 'text_of_option')]");

WebElement select = driver.findElement(bySelect);
select.click();
try {
    // wait at-most 5 seconds for element to become visible
    WebElement option = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(byOption)));   
} catch(TimeoutException t) {
    System.err.println("Timed out while waiting for dropdown to become visible: " + byOption.toString());
}
```

2) If the above doesn't work, you can be a little more invasive and execute some JavaScript to force the `option` to be selected.  This is only recommended as a last resort.

```java
public void selectDropdownByText(WebDriver driver, WebElement select, String text) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
        "var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]) {select.options[i].selected = true; }}", select, text);
}
```

Comment: I wrote it in Java, but if you're using C# or some other client bindings, it will be the same thing but with different syntax, of course.

Comment: I've rewritten it in C#. Don't understand the meaning of indexed arguments in JavaScript code. What is arguments[0]?

Comment: Oh, I should pass the element and option text as arguments to ExecuteScript, am I right?

Comment: Yes that's right.  The JavaScript provided in the first argument of `executeScript()` is wrapped in a function by Selenium and executed.  The rest of the parameters e.g. `select` and `text`, are passed to that function and accessible via the `arguments` array (an implicit feature of every JavaScript function).  In this case, `arguments[0]` is the DOM object for the `select` element, and `arguments[1]` is the text for the option to be selected.

Comment: select.options[i].text is not the value, it is a visible text, yep?

Comment: doesn't work. Very strange. I'll take a timeout for thinking a little bit more :)

Comment: If you can provide a link to the website, I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 2):

ok, Element is not visible exception is thrown because of "user-centric" behavior of selenium,
In my working experience i found out that,
Selenium is not able to select element which are not visible to clients.
I mean can't select those who not appears on UI Window,
Still those are you can inspect on HTML DOM but cant access through selenium.
When those are visible on screen you can very well select those elements.

solution is before finding out select tag you must click on it to get visible full options tags.
Clicking makes all options that needs to be selected are now visible to clients.
Then you find that select element and then select options under select tag. when those List of options are completely visible on screen.

Comment: I had the same idea but when I perform a click via Actions actions = new Actions(Driver);  actions.MoveToElement(comboBoxDiv).Click().Perform(); The list options appear for a millisecond (roughly speaking) and disappear and after that, I again can't select an option.

Comment: *"...strange behavior..."*, *"...limitation..."* Really?! Do you understand the purpose of Selenium? Can you as user handle invisible elements on page?

Comment: @Andersson well, actually the element is visible for a human being. It is not visible for a machine :)

Comment: @Andersson  and DebanjanB my appologies, please i tried to answer according to mine small experience with selenium. I have modified and used more specific word for it.

Comment: _visible for a human being. It is not visible for a machine_ :) can't take it more

Comment: @EngineerSpock , are you sure that your script checks the visibility of element *after* element is completely visible? Note that in this case milliseconds do matter

Comment: @AshishKamble , note that if you're using `Select` class visibility of options not really required, so no need in additional click on select node

Comment: @Andersson yes I'm sure. It is fully visible. For some reason it's unvisible for Selenium.

Comment: @EngineerSpock , in this case you're probably trying to handle wrong drop-down

Comment: @AshishKamble I appreciate your each and every contribution on StackOverflow. Some of your answers were pretty much helpful to the community. My previous comment was against a comment you have published earlier (now deleted). Thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: @DebanjanB don't see anything special in my comment. Automating complex modern web sites by Selenium is extremely challenging with plenty of workarounds and such. I don't see anything strange in the fact that an element is visible to me but unvisible to Selenium. There can be a dozen of intertangled reasons of why this is happenning in a way it is happenning.